# Sort the table - React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to build a filter to my table, I was testing but now I don't now how create an ascending and descending function for it, Can you help me! Thanks in advance!

```html
import axios from 'axios';

export function getDashboardList() {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8080/otimizacao_rank')
            .then(response => { dispatch([{ type: 'RANKPARAM_FETCHED', payload: response.data }]) })
    }
}

export function filterTable(tableList, filters) {

  
  
    var filteredTable = tableList;
//First the filters are mapped
    Object.keys(filters).map((it) => {
        // save the field name that the user selected
        const fieldName = filters[it].field;
        // Check the type of ordering that the user wants
        switch (filters[it].type) {    
            case '>':
                filteredTable = Object.keys(filteredTable).map((it) => {
                    // And here should be the logic for each operation,
                    filteredTable[it][fieldName] =  '1' // sort the table in ascending order
                   
                    return filteredTable[it]
                })
                break;
            case '<':
                filteredTable = Object.keys(filteredTable).map((it) => {
                   
                    filteredTable[it][fieldName] = '0' //sort the table in descending order
                    return filteredTable[it]
                })
                break;
        }
    })

    return { type: 'RANKPARAM_FILTERED', payload: filteredTable }

}
```

Comment: Why not use lodash https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy

Answer (score 0):

You should check out https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme

react-table is a lightweight, fast and extendable datagrid built for React

I had used it in one of my project and it’s simple.. let me know if you run into any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fixed data table. 
It allows an add-on feature for filtering and sorting the data elements in the table.

For more details, you can visit:
http://schrodinger.github.io/fixed-data-table-2/example-object-data.html